# SciFi novel about a portal/hole/doorway (possibly in the desert) from which random objects appear

Tags: story-identification, novel

I want to say this book was published anywhere from the 80's to the early 2000's. I believe the portal was in the desert in the US, and the government built a facility around it. Objects from the portal/hole/doorway were unlike any technology/substance known to humans.  The only specific object I remember was a super dense material, perhaps cloth like, that was incredibly heavy because of its density. The portal was one-way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Hi sorry! I want to say I read it anywhere from 2007-2012. I can't remember much about the cover. I don't think it had any people on it. I feel like it was a typical sci fi cover, perhaps of a landscape. It was also a modern day earth, not futuristic, except for the random-objects-flying-out-of-a-portal part 

Comment: Sounds similar to *From A Buick 8* (2002) by Stephen King, but there was no government facility. There was a police station nearby. Also the portal in *From A Buick 8* is two-way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it!! (Well, a kind stranger on reddit found it). [*The Breach* by Patrick Lee](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6987527). More of a thriller with sci-fi vibes. Thanks everyone for the help!

> Thirty years ago, in a facility buried beneath a vast Wyoming emptiness, an experiment gone awry accidentally opened a door. It is the world's best-kept secret-and its most terrifying. Trying to regain his life in the Alaskan wilds, ex-con/ex-cop Travis Chase stumbles upon an impossible scene: a crashed 747 passenger jet filled with the murdered dead, including the wife of the [P]resident of the United States.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted.

Comment: I'll be sure to do that as soon as possible! Thanks!